# TextField can not be entered in preview and simulator

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a very simple view with a `TextField` and a `Button`:

```
struct NewItem: View {
    private let limit = 50
    @State var keywords: String = ""
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Keywords", text: $keywords, axis: .vertical)
                .lineLimit(2)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .padding()
                .onChange(of: keywords) { oldValue, newValue in
                    keywords = ((newValue.count > limit) ? oldValue : newValue).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
                }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Add")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .padding()
                
            }
        }.navigationTitle("New keywords")
    }
    
    private func save() -> Void {
        print("save")
    }
}

#Preview {
    NewItem()
}
```

The issue that I have with the TextField is, I can not type any letter into it neither in the preview or in simulator.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using **XCode 15 beta 2**

**Update**
I have reduced the code to:

```
struct NewItem: View {
    private let limit = 50
    @State var keywords: String = ""
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Keywords", text: $keywords)
    }
}

#Preview {
    NewItem()
}
```

and still can not type into the textfield

Comment: @matt I have deleted the `onChange` modifier and still does not work.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. When I delete the onChange and other unknowns in your code, it works fine. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: The code works. Maybe you have disconnected the hardware keyboard. Try command + K